# Adding Intentional Ambiguity to Parser/Interpreter

Tags: python, algorithm, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree, interpreter

I've written a parser that properly takes an expression and creates an AST from it. My interpreter then takes that AST, evaluates it, and then returns a solution. However, I'd like the parser (or the interpreter) to account for ambiguity (lack of parenthesis) in an expression.

For example, if I write something like R ∩ G - B as an expression, I'd like to see ASTs for both (R ∩ G) - B and R ∩ (G - B) returned. I've seen many solutions to remove ambiguity when parsing an expression, but I'd like to be able to see all possible interpretations of an expression.

Here's a snippet from my parser class:

```
    def eat(self, token_type):
        if self.current_token.type == token_type:
            self.current_token = self.lexer.get_next_token()
        else:
            self.error()

    def factor(self):
        token = self.current_token

        if token.type in (COLOR, EMPTY_S, UNIVERSE_OP):
            self.eat(token.type)
            return Num(token)
        elif token.type == L_PAREN:
            self.eat(L_PAREN)
            node = self.expr()
            self.eat(R_PAREN)
            return node

    def term(self):
        node = self.factor()

        while self.current_token.type is COMPLIMENT:
            token = self.current_token
            self.eat(COMPLIMENT)

            node = BinOp(left = node, op = token, right = self.expr())

        return node

    def expr(self):
        node = self.term()

        while self.current_token.type in (UNION, INTERSECT, MINUS, SUBSET, EQUALS):
            token = self.current_token

            if token.type == UNION:
                self.eat(UNION)
            elif token.type == INTERSECT:
                self.eat(INTERSECT)
            elif token.type == MINUS:
                self.eat(MINUS)
            elif token.type == SUBSET:
                self.eat(SUBSET)
            elif token.type == EQUALS:
                self.eat(EQUALS)

            else:
                self.error()

            node = BinOp(left = node, op = token, right = self.expr())

        return node

    def parse(self):
        return self.expr()
```

With my current setup, the parser would return an AST for R ∩ (G - B) only.

Comment: @prune: I think OP is seeking *algorithmic* advice, not debugging. Algorithmic questions are completely in scope for SO, at least if they relate to a practical programming problem. A MCVE is not required (nor really possible).

Answer (score 1):

There are parsing algorithms that, for an ambiguous grammar, will find all possible ways to parse a given string: Earley, CYK, Tomita, GLR, GLL. But they're all pretty far from the recursive-descent parser you've got now. (GLL claims to be recursive-descent-like, but that seems a bit of a stretch.)

Answer (score 0):

The "obvious" way to do this, is to add additional grammar rules to the language your parser accepts.  What I mean by this, is first write down the grammar your recursive parser accepts; at present it only accepts on interpreation of expressions.    Add an explicit rule for the other interpretations; this defines the ambiguities.

Something like:

```
set_expression = intersection | set_expression '-' intersection;
intersection = term  |  intersection '∩'  intersection_term ;
term = primitive_set | term '∩' primitive_set ;
```

Now "just" adjust your parser to accept these rules.   To do that, your parser will probably have to implement saving of the parse state where it encounters an alternative, so that it can restore ("backtrack") and try the alternatives too.  This includes the point of the input stream at the alternative.  You can do this by buffering the input text and/or the input tokens.

Michael Dyck listed a variety of parsing engines/approaches that do this in a more regular way, but they all start with the assumption that your grammar explicitly includes the ambiguous alternatives.